# Mapstruct Subclass Mapping

Tags: java, spring, dto, mapstruct

I am trying to use mappers for subclasses. I have a Person that has 2 subclasses and another class that has 2 Person instances. I am having problems at mapping objects using mapstruct and Spring-boot.

I have these entities:

```
public class Person extends BaseEntityAudit {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String phoneNo;
}

public class RealPerson extends Person {

    private String identificationNo;
}

public class LegalPerson extends Person {
    private String taxNo;
}

public class Mediation extends BaseEntityAudit {

  
      
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,
            CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "first_party_id", nullable = false)
    private Person firstParty;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,
            CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "second_party_id", nullable = false)
    private Person secondParty;
    //...
}
```

And my mappers are:

```
@Mapper(subclassExhaustiveStrategy = SubclassExhaustiveStrategy.RUNTIME_EXCEPTION, uses = { RepresentativeMapper.class})
public interface PersonMapper {

    PersonMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(PersonMapper.class);

    @SubclassMapping(target=RealPersonDto.class, source= RealPerson.class)
    @SubclassMapping(target=LegalPersonDto.class, source= LegalPerson.class)
    @Mapping(target = "representativeDto", source = "representative")
    PersonDto toDto(Person person);

    @Mapping(target = "representativeDto", source = "representative")
    LegalPersonDto toDto(LegalPerson legalPerson);

    @Mapping(target = "representativeDto", source = "representative")
    RealPersonDto toDto(RealPerson realPerson);
}
@Mapper(uses = { PersonMapper.class })
public interface MediationMapper {

    MediationMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(MediationMapper.class);

    @Mapping(target = "firstPartyDto", source = "firstParty", qualifiedByName = "toDto")
    @Mapping(target = "secondPartyDto", source = "secondParty", qualifiedByName = "toDto")
    @Mapping(target = "id", source = "id")
    MediationDto toDto(Mediation mediation);

    Mediation toEntity(MediationDto mediationDto);

    List<MediationDto> toDtoList(List<Mediation> mediations);
}
```

I created a controller for both mediation and person. When I get all person objects I get them with the specific fields according to realPerson/legalPerson values. But when I use mediatiation's controller that has the mediationMapper I do not get these fields I rather get person dto's fields only.

Comment: Can you please share the generated code of the MediationMapper?